# Get localized names of Apple's first-party iOS apps for all languages?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, localization, internationalization

I'm working on localization for an iOS library that displays the name of first-party iOS apps (Maps, Safari, Mail, etc). It needs to support all languages supported by iOS, so I need *every* localized name for the first-party iOS apps I care about.

I can grab them manually for each language (by changing the language in the simulator and looking at the default apps, or visiting international marketing pages such as http://www.apple.com/fr/iphone-5c/built-in-apps/), but given the number of languages iOS is available in an automated solution would be much preferred.

Is there an easier method? Perhaps a way to extract the Info.plist file for each app out of the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

You may find these names in Apple glossaries. See http://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=localization